# Зависание во время установки CentOS на VMWare

Tags: centos, установка, vmware

Установил  vmware, на ней CentOS с netinstall, все идет хорошо, на последнем этапе   package instalation - зависает и не идет дальше от 0 %.

Answer (score 1):

А виртуальная сеть работает нормально? Выглядит, как если бы сеть отвалилась или DNS перестал работать. Еще, как вариант, в самом начале установки предлагается проверить носитель, т.е. диск. Посмотрите, может образ кривой.